# Счетчик публикаций в блоке "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь настроить на одностраничнике блок "поделиться" от Яндекса.
Установил код со счетчиком публикаций:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script> 
<div 
    class="ya-share2" 
    data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,blogger,lj" 
    data-counter="">
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что если использовать utm-метки, то считаются публикации по каждой метке.
Например, по адресу site.ru - 100 публикаций, но если добавить метку site.ru/?ch=vk - то 0 публикаций, хотя по факту страница одна.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вот код блока:
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,blogger,lj" data-counter=""></div>

Comment: Маловероятно, но посмотрите вот сюда https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru. Может каконический url поможет.

Comment: Спасибо. добавил rel="canonical", посмотрим

Comment: Была похожая проблема с виджетом комментариев ВКонтакте: 

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
 VK.init({apiId: 5275454, autoPublish: 1, onlyWidgets: true});
 VK.Widgets.Comments('vk_comments', {limit: 10, attach: false, pageUrl: "http:/site.ru"});
}
</script>

помогло добавление параметра pageUrl.. может есть такое же решение?)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете явно указать страницу, которой хотите поделиться.

```
<div class="ya-share2"
     data-url="https://example.org"
     data-counter></div>
```